# Clarification on GoDaddy policy for acquiring expiring domain name - power of initial registrant

Tags: domains, domain-registration, godaddy, domain-registrar

I've read conflicting reports on what happens when trying to acquire an expiring domain name through Godaddy. My primary concern is that they will not honor either an auction bid or a closeout purchase, in that the lapsed registrant can merely buy back the domain name through day 60 with an $80 redemption fee, irregardless of auction winners.

I've used this as a guide:
https://www.godaddy.com/help/expired-registration-recovery-policy-errp-compliance-statement-8803

My concern is rooted in anecdotes from online forums (the reason for this post) of Godaddy submitting to a customer request to reaquire their expired domain by the initial registrant paying a redemption fee and Godaddy disregarding the highest auction bidder or a closeout purchaser's purchase, which would obviously conflict with their statement in the second yellow highlited section:

> A registrant may renew an expired domain name at no extra cost up until
>   day 12. Starting on day 13, an $80 redemption fee will apply. **As long
>   as the domain was not won at expired auction or placed in backorder or
>   closeout**, the original registrant can attempt to redeem the domain up
>   until day 60 (with the additional $80 redemption fee)

Does anyone know how likely they are to make exceptions to their policy (i.e. is there something in their fine print) or anything to back up the anecdotes I've read?

Additionally, if they return the domain to the registry on day 43, how would the initial registrant be given preference through day 60 (is it locked to the public between days 43 and 60)?